# why does my script in unity not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made 2 scripts and assigned it to 2 cubes: "cube" and "cube 1".
Normally if you click on cube it sets a value so that when you click cube 1 it disappears.
If you click cube 1 first it's not gonna work.
So that's what I tried to make but it does not work and I don't understand why.

here are my scripts

**cube:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class script : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int test = 0; // make the variable for the value
    public  void OnMouseDown() // when the user click
    {
        test = 1; //make the value of test 1
    }
}
```

**cube 1**:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject a; //make a gameobject
    public script script; //make a variable where we put in the script
    void OnMouseDown() // when the user click
    {
        script = a.GetComponent<script>(); // get script

        if ( script.test == 1) //test or the variable test in the other script is 1
        {
        Destroy(gameObject); // destroy the object
        }
    }
}
```

---

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you add what actually is happening right now? EDIT: I'm sortof new to unity, but maybe, if you check the docs for [GetComponent()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html), it returns the component attached to the object you are calling the function on. So... probably do something like cube.GetCompoment()? Idk, just my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the `script` class to be capitalised.

```
public class Script : MonoBehaviour
```

Then in the `NewBehaviourScript1` change everything inside it to:

```
public class NewBehaviourScript1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Script script; //Drag the other cube onto this in the inspector.

    void OnMouseDown() 
    {
        if ( script.test == 1) 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); 
        }
    }
}
```

You should use more descriptive names for both your classes and their instances.

Note: For this to work you will **have to have drag the other cube onto the `script` variable in the inspector and it will have to have a `Script` attached to it.**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `a.GetComponent<script>();`. You need to pass a Type to GetComponent in order for it to work. I'm not sure that your code even compiles, its very hard to read it because you did not format it properly.